# How to Log HTTP Request and Response using Jetty Http Client

Tags: http, jetty-8

I am using Jetty's HttpClient to send requests. Looking for a way to log the request and response in Trace - to be enabled for troubleshooting.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: UPDATE: cloned the GIt repo for jetty 8 branch and working on a solution and doing a contribution to open source while I'm at it...

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is similar to what someone else asked about LifeCycle of a container, here is my answer:

Specifically RequestLog is what you want as you can intercept anything and deal with it.

LifeCycle interface is fairly basic , as you can use to register start, stop, failed, etc but not really requests/response to my knowledge.

I did do a research and found that this might be the best for you

[RequestLog interface](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.19.v20190610/org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog.html)

It's super interface is LifeCycle.

If you still do need to use AbstractLifecycle , simply "implements " it :) and override methods and watch for String based events (STOPPED , etc) , its all in the java doc.

Here you go

[AbstractLifeCycle - java doc](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.19.v20190610/org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/AbstractLifeCycle.html)

Comment: This doesn't help me out as I'm am looking for client side logging and RequestLogHandler is for the server side

Comment: Your question did not state that at all. Not to mention you would need to grab those things from server and possibly push them through to some tool, maybe ideally through socket... anyway i did answer how to get to logs as they happen

Comment: what do you mean? The title of the question clearly states: using Jetty Http Client...

Comment: Both links are broken